# Migrate from Mdaemon to postfix

Tags: postfix, migration, mdaemon

how can I move Inbox/Sent/Draft from Mdaemon to postfix?

is there any automatic way?

Comment: I have iredmail that use postfix

Answer (score 1):

You can use imapsync to syncronize IMAP folders.

Have a look at http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-migrate-mailboxes-between-imap-servers-with-imapsync